# How are the Boundary conditions for wave guides derived?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, boundary-conditions, waveguide

So I understand that for a linear material we get the equations where 1 is the material above a boundary and 2 is the new material below the boundary. $$E_1^{\parallel} - E_2^{\parallel}  = 0 $$
$$\epsilon_1 E_1^{\perp} - \epsilon_2E_2^{\perp}  = \rho_{free}$$ $$  B_1^{\perp} - B_2^{\perp}  = 0$$ $$ \frac{1}{\mu_1}B_1^{\parallel} - \frac{1}{\mu_2}B_2^{\parallel}  = J_{free}$$

and this is derived from Maxwell's equations and it makes sense.

What I am confused about is how that is done in the wave guide case since it is a conductor. I understand that in a perfect conductor, ignoring skin effects, $\vec{E}_{conductor} = 0$. So then why do we only say that at the boundary of the waveguide $$E^{\parallel} = 0 $$ $$B^{\perp}= 0$$ why do we not also say that $$E^{\perp} = 0 $$ $$B^{\parallel}= 0$$ since $E_{conductor} = 0$ ? I do not really understand how the waveguide boundary conditions are derived from Maxwell's equations. It seems that everywhere I look they are just stated with the only justification that  $E_{conductor} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

> why do we not also say that $$E^{\perp} = 0 $$

Because

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac {\rho} {\varepsilon_0}$$

and the ideal conductor can support an infinite charge density $\rho$. Therefore there can be a discontinuity in $\mathbf{E}$ at the surface of the conductor, and knowing that $\mathbf{E}=0$ inside the conductor doesn't help you determine $E^{\perp}$ in the dielectric material, even right at the boundary with the conductor.

Or, to put it in a more handwavy, qualitative way, the conductor contains free charge, possibly at infinite charge density, and free charge terminates electric field lines. However the field lines must enter the conductor perpendicular to the surface or they would produce infinite surface currents.

Comment: Can you elaborate again on how you can get away with a discontinuity at the surface of a conductor?

Comment: @realanswers, In a one-dimensional system, if the derivative of a function becomes a delta function, the original function has a discontinuity. In three dimensions, if the gradient has a delta function, then the field can have a discontinuity.